# How to set `environment_url` from environment variables

Tags: github-actions, github-enterprise

I have multiple envs that I am deploying to. (development, staging, production).

I am relying on the env context for some values like the AWS bucket name.

```
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    env:
      BUCKET: ${{ secrets.BUCKET }}
    environment:
      name: ${{ inputs.environment }}
      url: https://www.${{ env.BUCKET }}
    steps:
```

In my workflow I am getting:

> Skip setting environment url as environment 'development' may contain secret.

I also tried to refer it as $BUCKET but with no success (doesn't interpolate this fields)

Answer (score 0):

Github will automatically analyse your workflows to prevent any secrets to be reveal in any outputs (logs, puts, debugs, environment url, ...)

If the content of ANY SECRETS is present on your environmnet_url, this error message is occurred.

**For example:**

1. When your secrets "secrets.BUCKET" is resolved as `the-bucket`
2. When run a workflow if the string `the-bucket` is present in any part of the outputs (here environment_url), Github blocks the output to keep your secret.. Secret !

**NOTE**: Your secret is also keeped safe if you puts it in plain text like `format("https://pr-{0}-{1}.domain.dev", "1", "the-bucket")`. The result is `https://pr-1-***.domain.dev` and display error `Skip setting environment url as environment 'development' may contain secret.`

**Solution 1**

Don't put the bucket name in your secret and use directly an env var in your workflows

```yaml
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    env:
      BUCKET: the-bucket
    environment:
      name: ${{ inputs.environment }}
      url: https://www.${{ env.BUCKET }}
    steps: []
```

**Solution 2:** *More paintful*

If your bucket name needs to be absolutely secrets, create a redirection behind one of your domain and use this domain as url

```yaml
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    env:
      BUCKET: the-bucket
    environment:
      name: ${{ inputs.environment }}
      # redirect to https://www.{{ env.BUCKET }}
      url: https://www.my-secret-bucket.domain.tld
    steps: []
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks for the tip! Turns out my old GitHub Action setup was done before _variables_ was released and it was using _secrets_ to store a number of variables used in the workflow. After moving these variables from _secrets_ to _variables_, everything is fixed.