# Warning about setting environment url in GitHub

Tags: github, environment-variables, github-actions, warnings, workflow

Have one question about this:

```
environment:
  name: ephemeral
  url: https://some-subdomain.domain.com
```

Each time during workflow execution I am getting a warning:

> Skip setting environment url as environment 'ephemeral' may contain secret.

Honestly, I do not understand why it happens so as there is no secret inside url, but just plain text. Secrets are used only inside this step of the workflow, but they have no relation with this variable (there is no direct reference with url). Any ideas on how to fix this warning except url deletion?
Thanks!

Comment: Is that the exact format for `url` that you're using in your actual workflow? No secrets?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74029308/how-to-set-environment-url-from-environment-variables

Comment: Yep. It is actually the same text format. Unfortunatelly i can not show the exact url so as it is prohibited. But there are no any secrets in URL defenitelly. I have read already that related issue you have provided, and that case has some env or secret inside and that is clear. But in my case it is just a plain text. And it is really strange to get this warning. I even started to check wether there is some nested workflow inside this one which could has impact on this issue. And there is nested github tamplate where $ENVIRONMENT variable is being passed into helm chart. Checking this variant.

Comment: Right. Yes, you should investigate where it's coming from because according to ['jobs.<job_id>.environment'](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenvironment), "**The URL can be an expression and can use any context except for the `secrets` context.**".

Comment: Does the environment URL contains the word `secret` even without referring any github secrets?

Comment: According to [implementation](https://github.com/actions/runner/blob/97195bad5870e2ad0915ebfef1616083aacf5818/src/Runner.Worker/JobExtension.cs#L557-L560), there sure is something in your `url` that needs to be masked and is the cause of this warning.

Comment: @Azeem i even can`t imagine what it can be. There is just url for  our site, like https://api-something.domain.com. I even removed all the secrets inside all the steps and pasted there hardcoded values directly to check wether it will fix an issue (i suspected that another (not url) secrets coud cause this error. But after removal still geting warning that environment may hold the secrets and because of this github is masking the environment url. After all i have done, for me it sounds like nonsence to be honest.

Comment: @GuiFalourd no, there is no any word 'secret" inside, or $secret, or ${secret} or something like that. Just human readable format url starting from https:// at the beginning without any substiotions.

Comment: @kostyanius: Right. So, you have verified all the possibilities. Now, it starts to sound like a potential bug. You might want to [create an issue](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/new/choose) on the repo. They might have some logical explanation for it (if any) or provide a fix otherwise.

Comment: i am starting to suspect that this issue could be because of the next possible variants:

1) github issue (unlikely but still possible)

2)  uses: actions/checkout@v3 issue  or uses: azure/setup-kubectl@v3 (plugings we are using in this wrokflow steps)

3)  self hosted runner (old version) which does not recognize url correctly.

Have mo more ideas about this. Thanks for the help. Will keep you posted.

Comment: @kostyanius: After looking at the implementation, I wouldn't look anywhere else. [That warning is coming from the difference of `environment.url` and its masked version.](https://github.com/actions/runner/blob/97195bad5870e2ad0915ebfef1616083aacf5818/src/Runner.Worker/JobExtension.cs#L557-L560) Otherwise, there won't be any warning. You might want to deep dive into its [PR # 762](https://github.com/actions/runner/pull/762), just to make sure.

Comment: It could be interesting to test locally the [MaskSecrets function](https://github.com/actions/runner/blob/97195bad5870e2ad0915ebfef1616083aacf5818/src/Sdk/DTLogging/Logging/SecretMasker.cs#L209) with your URL value, to check what would be the output, and compare with the original value.

Comment: @GuiFalourd: I started to do this (https://godbolt.org/z/PG4hTKGvb) but it is part of `SecretMasker` class which in turn depends on other classes and interfaces as well e.g. `RegexSecret`, `ValueSecret`, etc. so I decided against it. The OP might want to do this for the actual value of `url`. But, it first needs a bit of cleanup to strip it down to the bare minimum for any kind of testing.

Comment: Finally found the root cause. Helm step in the github workflow had -set parameter that had reference on the domain, which had reference on the secret, which had reference on the url that matches with the declared env url variable. :lol: Now issue is solved. Thank you guys for superior support and assistance. )